# A readable way to pull in a hasMany collection into a result object in the controller

Tags: laravel, eloquent, crud

Inside a resource controller I have the following show function.

```
public function show(Invite $invite)
{
    return response($invite->jsonSerialize(), Response::HTTP_CREATED);
}
```

The invite model has many guests and the guest model belongs to an invite. Standard resource routes. When I query the url, I get a response like:

```
{
    id":17,
    "user_id":2,
    "event_id":1,
    "name":"Fred Neumann +1",
    "called":0,
    "emailed":0,
    "invited":1,
    "max_guests":2,
    "created_at":"2019-05-18 21:31:07",
    "updated_at":"2019-05-18 21:31:07",
    "deleted_at":null
}
```

Now I would also like to return the guests along with the invite info. I can achieve this by modifying the show function as such:

```
public function show(Invite $invite)
{
    // Don't remove this line:
    $invite->guests = $invite->guests;

    return response($invite->jsonSerialize(), Response::HTTP_CREATED);
}
```

This works fine but it's not obvious that it actually does anything. I could easily see myself removing it later by accident and breaking the API, hence the comment. Is there a more readable alternative?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Load the `guests` relationship with [lazy eager loading](https://laravel.com/docs/eloquent-relationships#lazy-eager-loading):

```php
public function show(Invite $invite)
{
    return response($invite->load('guests')->jsonSerialize(), Response::HTTP_CREATED);
}
```